# Wrong Data being sent to Mysql database from VB.net through paramatized insert statement

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, sql-insert

I am trying to insert data to mysql from vb.net. When I use concatenated sql query, it works well but when I make it paramatized, no error is shown by the vb.net try and catch statement, but wrong values and some null values are sent.

```
MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;userid=root;password=root;database=my_mysql_database"
Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
Try
    MysqlConn.Open()
    Dim Query As String
    'Query = "INSERT INTO my_mysql_database.edata(E_id,Name,Surname,Age,user_name,password, Gender)values('" & Txt_EID.Text & "', '" & Txt_Name.Text & "', '" & Txt_Surname.Text & "', '" & Txt_Age.Text & "', '" & Txt_User_Name.Text & "', '" & Txt_Password.Text & "', '" & Txt_Gender.Text & "')"'
    Query = "INSERT INTO my_mysql_database.edata 
             values(E_id=@Eid, Name=@Name, Surname=@Surname, Age=@Age,
             user_name=@UserName, password=@Pass, Gender=@Gender, DOB=@Dob,
             Image=@Ima, Email=@Email)"
    COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Eid", Txt_EID.Text)
    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Txt_Name.Text)
    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", Txt_Surname.Text)
    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", Txt_Age.Text)
    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Txt_User_Name.Text)
    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", Txt_Password.Text)
    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Txt_Gender.Text)
    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dob", DTP_Date.Value)
    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ima", Txt_Image.Text)
    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Txt_Email.Text)
    READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
    MsgBox("Added to Database")
    MysqlConn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    MysqlConn.Dispose()
End Try
```

When I do the paramatized way no error is shown, but a zero and all nulls are saved in mysql database.
[image]

During Debug I have checked the values stored in the parameters and they are correct, but what is sent to Mysql dataabse is a zero and all NULLS. What could be happening. How can Isend the correct values to Mysql Database

edit:
Here is a picture of datatypes
[image]

Comment: As for the image column in the database, I have set it as a varchar as I am making this is just to learn for now.

Comment: Are all these fields varchar fields or do you have some numerics (E_id. Age) ?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes They are numerics, But when I use the concatenated version there is no problem.

Comment: Well, try to put a Convert.ToInt32(textbox) around the parameter value. AddWithValue creates a parameter whose datatype is derived from the value passed. You pass strings and the parameter datatype will be a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be off here, if that is the case someone can educate me. My SQL knowledge tells me your query is wrong.

You say that this one work:

```
Query = "INSERT INTO my_mysql_database.edata(E_id,Name,Surname,Age,user_name,password, Gender)values('" & Txt_EID.Text & "', '" & Txt_Name.Text & "', '" & Txt_Surname.Text & "', '" & Txt_Age.Text & "', '" & Txt_User_Name.Text & "', '" & Txt_Password.Text & "', '" & Txt_Gender.Text & "')"'
```

So why change the format of the second query? INSERT INTO Table Values (Column=Value)
Surely it is supposed to be INSERT INTO Table (Column) Values (Value). Hence your query should look like this:

```
Query = "INSERT INTO my_mysql_database.edata (E_id,Name,Surname,Age,user_name,password,Gender,DOB,Image,Email) Values (@Eid,@Name,@Surname,@Age,@UserName,@Pass,@Gender,@Dob,@Ima,@Email)
```

Also, I strongly suggest you setup E_id to be auto incremental. Adding the ID yourself seems a bit unecessary.

Comment: Do you mean the one that says SET (column=value)? Because his query says VALUES. Oh the other post disapeared :D

Comment: Yes, that's probably the error, missing SET before the first value

Comment: Yes it was. Thanks to both for trying
PS the parmatized answer of Wozzec is missing the @Ima
here is the one that works
     Query = "INSERT INTO my_mysql_database.edata (E_id,Name,Surname,Age,user_name,password,Gender,DOB,Image,Email) values (@Eid,@Name,@Surname,@Age,@UserName,@Pass,@Gender,@Dob,@Ima,@Email)"

Comment: Ah, wops :D Glad it worked out for you. I'll update the post.

Comment: I am trying to so Update statement but an error is shown any Idea on this one

  Query = "UPDATE my_mysql_database.edata SET(E_id=@Eid, Name=@Name, Surname=@Surname, Age=@Age, user_name=@UserName, password=@Pass, Gender=@Gender, DOB=@Dob, Image=@Ima, Email=@Email) where E_id='" & Txt_EID.Text & "'"

Comment: Create a new question for it. I can't see anything wrong with it straight away.

Comment: It was the brackets. here is the one that works:
 Query = "UPDATE my_mysql_database.edata SET E_id=@Eid, Name=@Name, Surname=@Surname, Age=@Age, user_name=@UserName, password=@Pass, Gender=@Gender, DOB=@Dob, Image=@Ima, Email=@Email where E_id=" & Txt_EID.Text
                    thanks for the efforts anyway